# Extract lines between A and (B or C), containing D

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed, grep

I need to extract text between A and (B or C) patterns, that contains D pattern inside.

For example I have a file and need to extract all between "proc sql" and ("quit" or "run"), containing "index" inside.

```
proc sql
bla-bla-bla
index=10;
quit

proc sql
bla-bla-bla
quit;

proc sql
index=10;
run
```

Needed output:

```
proc sql
bla-bla-bla
index=10;
quit

proc sql
index=10;
run
```

By now I have such solution:

```
perl -0777 -lne 'print for grep /\bindex\b/i, /^proc sql.*?quit.*?\n/mgs' file
```

But it only extracts between "proc sql" and "quit" (NOT "quit" or "run"), containing "index". I don't know how to add OR operation.

If you can propose alternative awk/sed/grep solution - would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do as you ask. It accumulates into `$block` all the lines between the start and end patterns. When the end pattern is reached it prints the block if it contains `index`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $block;

while ( <DATA> ) {
  my $state = /^proc sql\b/ .. /^(?:quit|run)\b/;
  $block .= $_ if $state;
  if ( $state =~ /E/ ) {
    print $block, "\n" if $block =~ /^index=/m;
    $block = '';
  }
}

__DATA__
proc sql
bla-bla-bla
index=10;
quit

proc sql
bla-bla-bla
quit;

proc sql
index=10;
run
```

**output**

```
proc sql
bla-bla-bla
index=10;
quit

proc sql
index=10;
run
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that your input file is named input.txt, this will solve it in awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    procDetected = 0;
    indexDetected = 0;
}

/proc/ {
    buffer = "";
    indexDetected = 0;
    procDetected = 1;
}

/index/ {
    indexDetected = 1;
}

{
    if (procDetected) {
        # Add the line to the buffer.
        buffer = buffer $0 "\n";
    }
}

/run/ || /quit/ {
    if (procDetected && indexDetected) {
        print buffer;
    }
    procDetected = 0;
    indexDetected = 0;
}' input.txt
```